# Jackson form submit checkboxes

Tags: json, jackson

I have a form with checkboxes, on form submit.
If one checked, it comes in as string, if multiple checked, it comes in as an json array.

How do I get the object as an array?

```
TypeReference<HashMap> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap>(){};

    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);

    HashMap<String, Object> bean = mapper.readValue(formBean, typeRef);
```

`bean.get("somevarible")` < I want to get this as array regardless how many boxes checked

Thanks

**EDIT**

I am using this function, how can I update it?

```
    $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();

    $.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name]) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
    });
    return o;
    };
```

Comment: Then you need to make sure that the JSON always arrives as an array. This is a problem with your JSON generation, not your JSON parsing.

Comment: when I do bean.get, how do I assign it to an array?...

Comment: Also, that TypeReference is either unnecessary, or wrong: you are not defining key and value types. So you should do "TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>". Although that is not what causes specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue deserializing json (aka "the checkbox problem").  My (ugly) work-around was to use @JsonAnySetter to manually do the "right" thing with the incoming (string/list) value.

```
// q is always just a string.
@JsonProperty("q")
private String query;
// fq could be a string or a list.
private List<String> filterQuery;
// (get/set/add omitted)

// XXX - this is an evil hack to support 1 or >1 fq values 
// there must be a better way to support 2-way deserialization
@JsonAnySetter
void addEntry(String key, Object value)
{
    if ("fq".equals(key))
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            // can this even happen?
        } else if (String.class.equals(value.getClass()))
        {
            addFilterQuery((String) value);
        } else 
        {
            setFilterQuery((List<String>) value);
        }
    }
}
```